# Regex preg_replace_callback Convert in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have PHP code I need to convert to JavaScript code.

```php
$body = preg_replace_callback('/\{([^}]+)\}/', function ($match) {
  return $x[array_rand($x = explode('|', $match[1]))];
}, $body);
```

It returns a random string.

What is the equivalent JavaScript code?

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would do:

```
    $body = $body.replace(/\{([^}]+)\}/, ($0, $1) => {
      const values = $1.split('|');
      return values[(Math.random() * values.length) | 0];
    });
```